# How to change font size of chord names

Tags: lilypond

I am printing chord name using this code:

```
<<
  \chords {
    %\override ChordName.font-size = #8
    \chordmode {
      c 
    }
  }

  \relative c' {
    c d e f g a b c
  }
>>
```

It generates the following:

[image]

The chord name is bit too big for my taste. How do I change the font size?
I tried this:

```
\override ChordName.font-size = #8
```

This seems to *increase* the size just fine. But when I use a smaller value
such as 4, it seems to have no effect. What is the default size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

font-size is a relative number rather than an absolute. To make the number half size, for example, you'd use `\override ChordName.font-size = #-6`.  Here is the `ChordName.font-size` [entry](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/chordname) from the manual.

> font-size (number):
>
> 1.5
>
> The font size, compared to the ‘normal’ size. 0 is style-sheet’s normal size, -1 is smaller, +1 is bigger. Each step of 1 is approximately 12% larger; 6 steps are exactly a factor 2 larger. If the context property fontSize is set, its value is added to this before the glyph is printed. Fractional values are allowed.

Answer (score 3):

The font size property is a bit misnamed. It’s a size relative to the default text size. As such, small font sizes are achieved by giving negative values to the “font size”.

The default for ChordName is 1.5 as you can read here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/internals/chordname .